# vt_resize function: Cropping Issue

Tags: php, image-resizing

I've been using the vt_resize function to re-size images for my website, but have encountered a problem in regards to cropping recently.  I have copied and pasted the vt_resize function here: http://pastebin.com/u6K0H4ri

The vt_resize function dynamically resizes images using wordpress built in functions. It is called with the attachment id, the image url, a desired width, a desired height, and a variable indicating whether the image is to be cropped or not cropped.

Ideally I would like to be able to specify the size of an image through the width and height variables and the function would produce an image with those exact size specifications, not cropped.  However something fishy is throwing off the dimensions when the function is called.

For example:

```
  $pimage = vt_resize($thumb, '', 640, 278, false);
```

is called for two images (# 1: Original dimensions 8,704px X 2,332px) and (#2 4,096px X 2,340px), yet the function is not producing an image with 640 X 278.  Instead image # 1 is re-sized to 640px X 171px and image # 2 is re-sized to 486px X 278px. Apparently it is selecting one of the dimensions I am sending in, yet changing the second. I thought the problem may be with the wp_constrain_dimensions function call, so I attempted to comment $proportional_size variable out and directly set the $resized_img_path with $width and $height, but it was unsuccessful.  Any ideas?

Comment: as vt_resize() isn't a standard PHP function, you might want to provide a little more information about it... and not simply a link to pastie

Comment: I've added a short description of vt_resize().